# How do I get the position of dropped element inside the drop zone?

Tags: interact.js

I'm not sure I am wording this correctly. When an element is dropped into a drop zone I need to know the x/y position of the element in relation to the drop zone it is in.

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This should definitely be provided by the library but since it isn't, this is how I accomplished it:

```
  ondrop: function (event) {
    var dropzonePostion = $(event.target).position(),
    elementPosition = $(event.relatedTarget).position(),
    x = elementPosition.left - dropzonePostion.left,
    y = elementPosition.top - dropzonePostion.top;
  }
```